Invalid Argument Type Error with Knitting to PDF in RStudio
I am knitting a PDF and keep getting an error that references this particular line in my code.
Any advice?
Thanks!
library(forcats)
library(knitr)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)

bll_summarized <- bll_nyc %>% 
  mutate(borough_id = factor(borough_id, levels = c("1", "2", "3","4","5"), labels = c("Bronx", "Brooklyn", "Manhattan", "Queens", "Staten Island"))) %>%
  group_by(borough_id) %>% 
  summarize(counts_of_bll_greater_than_5 = sum(bll_5)) %>% 
  mutate(borough_id = fct_reorder(borough_id, bll_summarized$counts_of_bll_greater_than_5, .desc = FALSE))
bll_summarized
                

                                                                                          
Error in `!continue`:
! invalid argument type
Backtrace:
  1. rmarkdown::render(...)
  2. knitr::knit(knit_input, knit_output, envir = envir, quiet = quiet)
  3. knitr:::process_file(text, output)
  6. knitr:::process_group(group)
  7. knitr:::call_block(x)
  8. knitr:::block_exec(params)
  9. knitr:::eng_r(options)
 12. knitr (local) evaluate(...)
 13. evaluate::evaluate(...)

Quitting from lines 232-248 [unnamed-chunk-14] (problem_set_5_arjun.Rmd)
Execution halted

Unsure what else to try

Maybe you can format your code so that is is seen as code? A reproducible example to copy and paste, will also be more tempting to people to try to see if the error is reproducible and maybe think about a solution

It's harder than it sounds to create a reprex of an error message, especially from complex markdown. It seems that some recent R-Studio update or knitr update has broken the formerly good error reporting.
I am getting the same verbatim error message as the OP, and I doubt I have the same error in my code.
So this means that a generic and uninformative error message is getting triggered by a variety of different errors. Anybody know of which update this started on? I'm using R 4.1, Rstudio 2023.12.1 build 402, knitr version 1.46
